# How can I add a dynamic field to a Dojo store?

Tags: dojo

I have an Observable dojo.store.JsonRest store that is wrapped in a dojo.data.ObjectStore for use with a dijit.form.Select widget.

Each store item has a name field and a code field that I would like to format and present as the label.

By adding a get function to each item, I can add code to return a formatted string for a virtual label field.

However, how can I add the get function to all items in the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up making use of onFetch on the ObjectStore.

```
var setLabel = function(item) {
    item.label = item.name + ' (' + item.code + ')';
};
var store = new dojo.data.ObjectStore({
    objectStore: myObservableJsonRestStore,
    onFetch: function (results) {
        result.forEach(setLabel);
    }
});
```

If there are tidier alternatives, I'd be keen to know them.